# UE Boom 2 stutters with MacBook Pro when using browser

Tags: macbook-pro, safari, audio, bluetooth, spotify

My UE Boom 2 stutters when using it with a web browser on my MacBook Pro with macOS Sierra. I can play Spotify fine if I just have it up front but if I push it to the background and try to browse the web, it starts stuttering. I can't play anything from the web either since it stutters from the start. My iPhone plays on the bluetooth speaker just fine but it's my MacBook that's having the problem. Has anyone else had this issue?

Comment: Happened to me. Drove me nuts. Had to buy a new Bluetooth adapter. Which probably isn't a desirable solution on a laptop. :(

Comment: I'd suggest you using a different browser for testing. If it doesn't happen, you can confirm is the browser and you can maybe reset/reinstall it. Another thing you could try is creating a new user account and see if you can still replicate the issue. Basically, you need to troubleshoot and test.

Comment: I dont think it has anything to do with the browser. I have exactly the same problem and it happens regardless of brower, or if Im listening to music on itunes, or whatever. It happens with other bluetooth speakers too. Seems to be apples bluetooth implementation is just bad, and it seems to be worse in the new big sur previews. Stopping and starting bluetooth helps, as does strangely changing my wifi network.

Comment: I had this issue with my UE Boom 2 as well but it was happening on my Mac and my phone so I think it's the Bluetooth speaker itself that is problem. It just started happening today and I have had the speaker for several years. I think it's dying.

Answer (score 1):

Go to a store and buy USB bluetooth dongle (I bought the smallest I could find for $8). Plug it in and MacBook automatically shuts down onboard Bluetooth and uses the new USB. After that the music plays perfectly without any stutters at all!